Rotten Rim Joist & Sill Plate
1962 house in Canada (cold climate). In the process of insulating my rim joist cavity properly with 2in XPS. Previously it had insulation stuffed in, this particular area is very rotten. The other areas I've done so far in basement were fine or had minor black spots.
https://imgur.com/a/GMHNGsj
Could this be caused by the fiberglass insulation or is water getting in from somewhere?
How should I approach fixing this?

Rot needs moisture(usually).  The insulation did help to hold water longer against the wood.  Might be a plumbing leak but most likely rain/snow/ground water is coming in a bit.

It’s almost certainly water from outside… elevation-wise, where is the rim relative to ground level? And is that sidewalk tilting water toward the house?

Sill is sitting 2ft above grade. That sidewalk is sloping away. The wood is dry so I'm assuming it was an old leak previous owners covered up?

Might not be covered up. Just a leak they did not know went behind the insulation.  Insulation acts a bit like a sponge, it holds water and takes a long time to dry.
